# Changing CSS properties on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, opacity, transition

I'm designing a HTML/CSS template . I've the header with a CSS3 gradient and a relative position .
I want . When the visitor start to scroll down . The header properties changes to another properties .
Can i do this with jQuery ? 
and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but combining `$(window).scroll` and checking `$(window).scrollTop()` should be a good start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

```
$(your-selector).scroll(function() {

 $(your-object-to-change-css).addClass('new_class');
 $(your-object-to-change-css).removeClass('old_class');

});
```

Comment: Thanks very much . it worked great , But ! When i came to the default position it stills with the scrolling class .

Comment: @KhalidKhalil In that case, you need to check for this inside the `.scroll()` handler: `if(window.scrollTop == 0) { $("#header").removeClass("scrollClass"); }`.

Comment: yep , that's what i want exactly but this code unfortunately didn't work . check out :
$(window).scroll(function() {
   $("header").addClass('scroll');
   
   if(window.scrollTop == 0) {                    $("header").removeClass('scroll') };
 });